# IIS Application Pool configured to specific User MSA Account Through Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, powershell-5.0, iis-10

I am not sure why it's happening but I am stuck in a point when I am trying to Configure my AppPool with a Specific Account i.e. MSA or Service Account.

I am running below script in PowerShell to do the configuration:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\AppPool -name processModel -value @{userName="$user_name";password="$password";identitytype=3}
```

The problem is that whenever I put Service account details through this script the AppPool is getting stopped and When try to start the AppPool multiple time the service account is getting locked.
When I try to Configure manually in the AppPool it's working fine and works as Expected.

For Testing I tried to put my own ID credential in the above script and then its working fine as expected, but when I tried again with Service Account the result is same as above.

I tried multiple scripts to do so and result is same, in one of the script I found a strange error:

```
Set-ItemProperty : Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))
At line:8 char:1
+ Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\AppPool -name processMode ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-ItemProperty], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand
```

Can anyone help me to configure the Service Account in AppPool.

Comment: I can only think of a few things: 1) The identitytype needs to be a different value for managed service accounts. If it is not `3`, then it is `2`. 2) `$user_name` or `$password` contains special characters that interpolate differently than expected. You could type `$user_name` or `$password` at the prompt to verify this. 3) Create the `processModel` using the GUI. Then run `Get-ItemProperty` against it afterwards to see what the values are.

Comment: @AdminOfThings first of all this is my ASG server in AWS and I need to run this command in userdata so that everytime server comes up it's been configured with the service account so no prompt and no GUI. 2nd thing type 2 is not a valid type for entering the service account details. 3rd thing may be there is a issue with special character but i have only two special character i.e. '^' and '*' and idon't think so its making any issue.

Comment: you could try to modify the default IIS cache flushing behavior [link](http://itproctology.blogspot.com/2011/10/iis-powershell-and-type-mismatch-when.html)